# Install Qt 4.8.6 on Mac OS X El Capitan failed

Tags: macos, installation, qt4, osx-elcapitan

I was using Qt 4.8.6 on Mac OS X Yosemite before. I have just upgraded to El Capitan but then I cannot open Qt project with Qt 4.8.6 kit. I tried to remove and reinstall Qt 4.8.6.
I don't know why Qt 4.6.6 cannot be installed on new Mac OS X El Capitan. How about you? Can you verify me that Qt 4.8.6 cannot be installed on Mac OS X El Capitan?
Thank you very much!

//Edit: It seems that there is a same problem: https://forum.qt.io/topic/60173/install-qt-4-8-7-on-a-mac-running-os-x-10-11-el-capitan/6

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though there are some APIs used by Qt 4.8 that were removed with the release of OS X 10.11. As the current version 4.8.7 is (planned to be) the last of the 4.8 family according to the [4.8.7 release notes](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/05/26/qt-4-8-7-released/), you'll need to patch and compile Qt yourself as discussed in the [MacPorts Trac](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixpPGjkrvKAhWL2ywKHfzNAigQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftrac.macports.org%2Fticket%2F48129&usg=AFQjCNGe1-tQmjq1UCoPuqL5cDTajMgwQQ).

The convenient alternative is installing via homebrew or MacPorts. I've told homebrew to build Qt 4.8.7 for me and it works fine.

Apart from that it is strongly advised to upgrade to Qt 5.x due to support for 4.x running out - if you're not bound by external constraints like me. ;) (Source: also the release notes post)